# Get names of a color based on alpha value

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, rgba

Let say I supply R with a color name `'#023e8a'`

Now I want to get 5 following color names with alpha values as `c(0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2)`, which will be passed to `ggplot` as `fill` aesthetics.

Is there any function available in `R` or `ggplot` to achieve this? I know that in `ggplot` I could pass alpha values in any layer, but I want to get specific names of the color shades.

Any pointer will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to get the color "names" with alpha applied would be to use `scales::alpha`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:5],
  y = 1:5
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, fill = x)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = scales::alpha('#023e8a', c(0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
```

[image]

If instead of adding transparency you just want different shades of a color then perhaps `colorspace::lighten` is more appropriate:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, fill = x)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorspace::lighten('#023e8a', 1 - c(0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scales::alpha`:

```r
library(scales)
alpha("#023e8a", c(0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2))
#[1] "#023E8ACC" "#023E8A99" "#023E8A80" "#023E8A4C" "#023E8A33"
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good and I would use them.

However, if you are trying to reduce package dependencies, you can create a function that appends the hex value of each scaled alpha value to the color code:

```r
append_alpha  <- function(color, alpha) {
    alpha_scaled  <- round(alpha*255)
    alpha_hex  <- as.hexmode(alpha_scaled)
    color_with_alpha  <- paste0(color, alpha_hex)

    return(color_with_alpha)
}

alpha_values  <- c(0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2)
append_alpha("#023e8a", alpha_values)
# "#023e8acc" "#023e8a99" "#023e8a80" "#023e8a4c" "#023e8a33"
```

If you are reducing dependencies because you are building code that other people will use, you will want to add some error handling for blank strings, invalid colors etc.